# How do I add inaccessible parameters in a recursive function in c#?

Tags: c#, recursion, parameters, private

I am trying to write a Recursive function with necessary parameter, but I don't want some of the parameters to be used when calling the function.

And I know how to make optional parameters, but I still want to know if it's possible to make something like a 'private  parameter':

for example, a function which returns the value a number powered by 10:

```
static int foo(int par, private int count = 0)
{
    if (count == 9)
    {
        return par;
    }
    return foo(par, count + 1) * par;
}
```

In the function foo, I want the parameter 'count' to be inaccessible or private.

Comment: the accepted answer of the duplicate indeed provides the best possible answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make paramters in a method call private, only the complete method. With some overloading, this is possible:

You could do something like this:

```
private static int foo(int par, int count = 0)
{
    if (count == 9)
    {
        return par;
    }
    return foo(par, count + 1) * par;
}

public static int foo(int par)
{
    return foo(par, 0);
}
```

Comment: there is no need to repeat the answer from the duplicate question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner delegate (as `Func<int, int>`) to encapsulate the actual work and capture `count` using a closure (that will spare you from the need to pass `count` as a parameter):

```
static int foo(int par)
{
    int count = 0;
    Func<int, int> f = null;

    f = x =>
    {
        if (count == 9)
            return par;

        count++;
        return f(x) * x;
    };

    return f(par);
}
```